# Aligning text in a minipage environment with the top of a table in a tabular environment

Tags: tables

I would like the text in the `minipage` environment aligned with the top of a table in a `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}


\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."


\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}{3.5in}
\textbf{16.) }\raggedright{The table shows certain function values of $f$. \\If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$?}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$-5$ \\
\> \textbf{b.) }$-1$ \\
\> \textbf{c.) }0 \\
\> \textbf{d.) }2 \\
\> \textbf{e.) }4
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\stackon{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||} \hline
    $x$ &   $f(x)$ \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    2   &   $-1$ \\ \hline
    3   &   0 \\ \hline
    4   &   2 \\ \hline
    5   &   $-3$ \\ \hline
    6   &   4 \\ \hline
    7   &   $-5$ \\ \hline
    8   &   6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}{\bfseries\Longstack{Certain Function\cr Values of \boldmath$f$}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

[image]

For above code I use two mini pages aligned at top and omit `stackengine` package and its macro. Also I add `siunitx` package for nicer settings of numbers in table. Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{array,makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\textbf{16.)} 
\raggedright{The table shows certain function values of $f$. \\If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$?}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$-5$ \\
\> \textbf{b.) }$-1$ \\
\> \textbf{c.) }0 \\
\> \textbf{d.) }2 \\
\> \textbf{e.) }4
\end{tabbing}
    \end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}\centering
    \textbf{
Certain Function\\ 
Values of $f$}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|| c | S[table-format=-1.1] ||} \hline
    $x$ &   {$f(x)$} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    2   &   -1 \\ \hline
    3   &   0 \\ \hline
    4   &   2 \\ \hline
    5   &   -3 \\ \hline
    6   &   4 \\ \hline
    7   &   -5 \\ \hline
    8   &   6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a nice display!  I like that your code doesn't use `stackengine`.  I have used it for other code; so, I think that I will keep it in my own code.

Comment: if you will stick to use of  `stackengine` in this particular case, you will need to adjust vertical position of `stackon` manualy as it is shown in Bernard's answer, or put `minipage` and `stackon` in another `tabular(x)` environment. it is up to you, what you more prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\belowbaseline[shift]{…}` defined in `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{stackengine}
 \setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\textbf{16.) }\raggedright{The table shows certain function values of $f$. \\If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$?}
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3em} \= \kill
\> \textbf{a.) }$-5$ \\
\> \textbf{b.) }$-1$ \\
\> \textbf{c.) }0 \\
\> \textbf{d.) }2 \\
\> \textbf{e.) }4
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.75cm}
%
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\belowbaseline[-7pt]{\stackunder{\bfseries\Longstack{Certain Function\cr Values of \boldmath$f$}}{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c | S[table-format=-1.0] ||} \hline
    $x$ & {$f(x)$} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
    2 & -1 \\ \hline
    3 & 0 \\ \hline
    4 & 2 \\ \hline
    5 & -3 \\ \hline
    6 & 4 \\ \hline
    7 & -5 \\ \hline
    8 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:* I also suggest you take a look at the `tasks` package for the layout of exercises.

Comment: Using `[t]` as an option in the `minipage` environment, I had set the baseline of it to be at the top of the box surrounding the text.   Is the baseline of the `tabular` environment also at the top?  How did you decide on `-7pt`?

Comment: Measurement with my viewer (SumatraPDF) gave me 7 pt (precision: 0.1pt). I didn't decide whatever for tabular. It you set `[t]`, it's the second line of the ‘caption’ which is aligned, so I had to do it by hand, through the `\belowbaseline` command.

Answer (score 2):

The input can be simplified with some more `tabular` environments. The trick is to use `\begin{minipage}[t]` and `\begin{tabular}[t]`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\bfseries\boldmath #1}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{3.5in}
\raggedright
\textbf{16.) }The table shows certain function values of $f$. \\
If $g(x) = f(3x + 1)$, what is the value of $g(2)$? \\[2ex]

\hspace*{3em}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\textbf{a.) }$-5$ \\
\textbf{b.) }$-1$ \\
\textbf{c.) }0 \\
\textbf{d.) }2 \\
\textbf{e.) }4
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.75cm}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\bfseries Certain Function \\
\bfseries\boldmath Values of $f$ \\[1ex]
\begin{tabular}{|| c | c ||}
\hline
$x$ &   $f(x)$ \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
2   &   $-1$ \\ \hline
3   &   0 \\ \hline
4   &   2 \\ \hline
5   &   $-3$ \\ \hline
6   &   4 \\ \hline
7   &   $-5$ \\ \hline
8   &   6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The table on the right is quite ugly, in my opinion, so I suggest an alternate form.

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\bfseries Certain Function \\
\bfseries\boldmath Values of $f$ \\[1ex]
\begin{tabular}{c | c}
$x$ &   $f(x)$ \\
\hline
2   &   $-1$ \\
3   &   0 \\
4   &   2 \\
5   &   $-3$ \\
6   &   4 \\
7   &   $-5$ \\
8   &   6 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]